# Both folder vs lib folder meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

As I understand it in meteor you can have a `both` folder along with a `lib` folder. Both folders hold code that are pertinent to both the client and the server, such as iron-router routes or meteor collection definitions. Is there a difference between the two folders or are they the exact same thing?

Comment: both appears to just be a random name, if you name a folder aoth, its contents will load before both. so it would go lib then aoth then both. lib is a thing, but both is not a thing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both code would act as the same thing, just the `lib` folder would have a preference with regard to loading order.

Files in the `lib` directory would be loaded first, before the ones in the `both` directory. This can be useful for helpers and constants and stuff you need to be ready before anything else loads.

Comment: Note that there's nothing special about the name `both`. Anything that isn't in either `client` or `server` executes on the server and the client. You can also use `client/lib` and `server/lib`. See the [Meteor documentation on directory structure](http://docs.meteor.com/#structuringyourapp).

Comment: @Nate is it from a tutorial or a blog post? I think the intention of it is that code runs on both the client and server. If you had your code in a folder such as `client` it would run on just the client (same with server). Check out the link in the first comment for special directory names

Comment: I just read the link @user3374348 posted. @akshat it was from a tutorial and I understand the use now. The arbitrarily named `both` folder was set up for common code (to both the client and server) in the tutorial. However a folder name `whatever` would have the same functionality as the `both` folder. Thanks!